# TTS truncates audio in the middle of the recording - skips few sentences

Tags: text-to-speech, truncate, google-text-to-speech

When I send the request with text input to Google TTS sometimes it truncates sentences in the middle and returned audio is unusable. Sometimes it works as expected. I checked that the only limitation is 5000 bytes per request but I am far away from that count. Could someone help me with this?

I checked my request message and it contains whole text and no special characters are there just the text.

Problem you have encountered:
Google TTS sometimes returns incomplete audio recording. Trancutes few sentences in the middle.

What you expected to happen:
Google TTS sends always full recording.

I verified what information I am sending to the TTS service.

Comment: Which voice are you using?